# Access the same Task from multiple methods (actions)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, task

I am trying to perform an import process by an Async controller, where I have a Task declared so that all methods can access it, but when the Task process finishes it is getting null and I can not see information from it from another method .

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class ImportController : AsyncController
{  
 private Task<ResultObject> _myTask;

 public ActionResult Import()
 {
     _myTask = Task.Run(() => {
         //failed or Success
         return new ResultObject();
     });

     _myTask.Wait();

     return Json(new { success : _myTask.Result });
 }

 public ActionResult CheckImportProcess()
 {
     //here _myTask is Null
     if(_myTask.Status == TaskStatus.Running){
         return Content("IS RUNNIN");
     }
     else{
         return Content(_myTask.Result);
     }
 }
```

}

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**
I tried using Hangfire to do this, but it was not possible. My import method should return a list of errors, and with Hangfire it is not possible to access the return of a run.

Comment: Why should the methods access the *task* instead of its results? Not that they *can*. Each request results in a different controller instance. If you want to create a long running job, that's not the way to do it.

Comment: Check Scott Hanselman's [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx). It explains why what you ask won't work, how to properly start a background task with QueueBackgroundWorkItem and how to implement scheduled jobs eg with Hangfire

Answer (score 0):

A new instance of `ImportController` is getting created every time you make a request, so the non-static `_myTask` field will be initialized to a null value on each of those other requests.

You could fix this by making `_myTask` static, or by injecting some kind of singleton-scoped manager class to keep track of your tasks outside the scope of the controller.

```
private static Task<ResultObject> _myTask;
```

However, this is going to be highly fragile in its current state. What happens if two different users kick off this task? Should it be running twice? Should you lose track of the first run because the second one got started? The way you're approaching this problem seems very much prone to cause problems, and I agree with Panagiotis that you probably ought to be using a different framework for firing and tracking the status of tasks.